# How to enable Javascript indentation in VisualStudio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In VisualStudio 2008 how to enable Javascript indentation? The code copied from from one users IDE is getting changed when opened in other users IDE. If there is provision to indent automatically, it will be easy to maintain the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. By default VisualStudio 2008 doesn't support indentation for Javascript. But after installing [VisualStudio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en), indentation is being done in Javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

use jslint

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/JSLintVS.aspx